# TV cannot see USB drive since Windows 7 ran repair tool

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive, ntfs, tv

I store media from Windows 7 to a portable NTFS USB drive and watch on my LG TV (circa 2015 model).

One night I booted Win 7 with the drive already connected. Windows detected something wrong with the drive and begun repairing it automatically. I think it ran Chdsk. Looked like it was correcting bad partitions, updating Master Boot Record etc.

However, after this "repair" my TV could not recognise the USB drive. It momentarily detects when the drive is inserted but the external storage page has a warning implying no drive is connected.

Win 7 still sees all the data.

I assume the TV formatted some bytes to use the drive but Windows 7 "erased" these?

Is there a way to have the drive working on both devices?
Can I repair the drive without having to move the data (although might be a good idea doing this)?

Comment: The TV wouldn't have an option to format? Sure it was ntfs before?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille The drive is NTFS right now and I'm sure chdsk didn't change it, so it's always been NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can let the TV reformat the stick: [LG support](https://www.lg.com/uk/support/product-help/CT00008334-1435837452345)

Comment: Thanks. But assuming it was NFTS all along, how could the TV read the drive but then Windows 7 complain and repair it? The TV must have written to the drive to change it?

Comment: If your TV can format the drive, it can write to the drive.  I disagree with your reasoning that it can't have changed the filesystem type. Did you ever put a file larger than 4Gb on it? If so, is that still possible?

Comment: Apparantly, both NTFS and exFAT can handle files larger than 4Gb, so that can't be the problem. But since the LG probably has a Linux OS, I would have expected exFAT.